# Difference between git log with and without <path> when only <path> was changed?

Tags: git

When I have two branches that have been merged, and in each one the same change was made independently, the git log of that file shows only one of these instances, while the git log of the entire repo shows both.  Why is that?

Here is where I created a change:

```
example:/test # git branch
* master
example:/test # cat > testfile 
aoeu
example:/test # git add -u; git commit -m "Add aoeu"
[master 34513b3] Add aoeu
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Then I put the same change on the alternate branch:

```
example:/test # git checkout -b alternate HEAD^
Switched to a new branch 'alternate'
example:/test # git cherry-pick -n master
example:/test # git commit
[alternate 52efabd] Add aoeu
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Now I merge the two branches, and look at the results.  Why don't I see commit 34513b3 in the output of the first "git log"?

```
example:/test # git merge master
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
example:/test # git log --oneline --graph testfile
* 52efabd Add aoeu
* d7a9a91 Initial commit
example:/test # git log --oneline --graph
*   838c5fd Merge branch 'master' into alternate
|\  
| * 34513b3 Add aoeu
* | 52efabd Add aoeu
|/  
* d7a9a91 Initial commit
```

Of course, it doesn't matter which branch I'm on:

```
example:/test # git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
example:/test # git merge alternate
Updating 34513b3..838c5fd
Fast-forward
example:/test # git log --oneline --graph testfile
* 52efabd Add aoeu
* d7a9a91 Initial commit
```

How does git decide which of these commits is the official one?  And why does it matter whether we look with file scope or full repo scope?  How can I get the behaviour I expect, i.e. to show all commits which are ancestors of HEAD and which are touching the affected file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is buried in the [`git rev-list` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) (this same text is included in the [`git log` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) but since virtually everything uses `rev-list`, I think it's the right place to remember as your general lookup location):

> **History Simplification**
>   Sometimes you are only interested in parts of the history, for example
>    the commits modifying a particular <path>. But there are two parts of
>    History Simplification, one part is selecting the commits and the other
>    is how to do it, as there are various strategies to simplify the
>    history.
>
> The following options select the commits to be shown:
>
> <paths>
>
> Commits modifying the given <paths> are selected.

[snip]

> The following options affect the way the simplification is performed:
>
> Default mode
>
> Simplifies the history to the simplest history explaining the final
>    state of the tree. Simplest because it prunes some side branches if
>    the end result is the same (i.e. merging branches with the same
>    content)
>
> `--full-history`
>
> Same as the default mode, but does not prune some history

You're using the default mode when you (presumably) want `--full-history` mode.  Note that history simplification gets activated when you use the <paths> notation to introduce history selection: that's why you *don't* need `--full-history` without it.

Comment: I think what I really want is `--full-history --no-merges`.  Thanks!